# Pandas Dataframe detect and retrieve data from "clusters" of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe where I want to detect some "clusters" of data.

After applying a filter the index column looks for example like this:

```
Index Column1
205    
256    
322    
423    
424
425
```

In this case, I'd like to retrieve data from rows 423, 424, 425 (are they are following each others)

Or sometimes it looks like that:

```
Index Column1
205    
256    
322    
423    
425
428
612
```

And I want to retrieve data from 423, 425 and 428 as they are "next to each other"

Comment: If it is always `...` then you can do something like this `df[~df['Column1=="..."]]`

Comment: sorry if the ... were misleading. Column1 is actually filled with a bunch a various values